# Stop trimming of whitespace when splitting a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

When using the text to columns feature in Excel to split a single column into two columns, I find that the second column has leading whitespace trimmed. Is there any way to force Excel to leave this intact? I can get around this by instead using the LEFT() and RIGHT() worksheet  functions to extract the left and right parts of the single column, but this is more time consuming when I have to do this repeatedly.

I'm using Excel 2010.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, the Trim function returns a text value with the leading and trailing spaces removed. `=trim(A1)` will do exactly what you're speaking about for cell or cell range; I always trim my text to columns with a drag down and `paste special - values`